# how to hide Toast messag from showing up

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I have Two Activity **A** activity and **B** activity, Inside **B** activity there is fragment where I have populated it with a list of an item from BlogRecycleadapter class.

When the Internet is not available, In **B** activity it shows "Check Internet", but when I press back button and move to **A** activity, Still toast message appears.

How do I hide the Toast message from appearing on First Activity i.e **A** activity??

My `RecycleViewAdapter` class is

**BlogRecyclerAdapter.java**

```
package com.nepalpolice.cdp;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

import static com.android.volley.VolleyLog.TAG;
import static com.nepalpolice.cdp.webfaq.isNetworkStatusAvialable;

public class BlogRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BlogRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<BlogPost> blog_list;
    public Context context;

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private PopupWindow popWindow;

    public BlogRecyclerAdapter(List<BlogPost> blog_list){

        this.blog_list = blog_list;


    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.blog_list_item, parent, false);
        context = parent.getContext();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

        final String blogPostId = blog_list.get(position).BlogPostId;
        final String currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        String desc_data = blog_list.get(position).getDesc();
        holder.setDescText(desc_data);

        String image_url = blog_list.get(position).getImage_url();
        String thumbUri = blog_list.get(position).getImage_thumb();
        holder.setBlogImage(image_url, thumbUri);

        String user_id = blog_list.get(position).getUser_id();
        //User Data will be retrieved here...



        firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                    String userName = task.getResult().getString("name");
                    String userImage = task.getResult().getString("image");

                    holder.setUserData(userName, userImage);


                } else {

                    //Firebase Exception

                }

            }
        });

        try {
            long millisecond = blog_list.get(position).getTimestamp().getTime();
            String dateString = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", new Date(millisecond)).toString();
            holder.setTime(dateString);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        //Get Likes Count
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").addSnapshotListener(((Main2Activity) context),new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

               if (e!=null) {
                   Log.w(TAG, "listening failed",e);
                   return;
               }

                if(!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()){

                    int count = documentSnapshots.size();

                    holder.updateLikesCount(count);

                } else {

                    holder.updateLikesCount(0);

                }

            }
        });

        if (InternetStatus.getInstance(holder.blogLikeBtn.getContext()).isOnline()) {
            //Get Likes
            firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).addSnapshotListener(((Main2Activity) context), new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "listening failed", e);
                        return;
                    }

                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_accent));
                        } else {
                            holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_accent));
                        }
                    } else {

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_gray));
                        } else {
                            holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_gray));
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

        }else{

            Toast.makeText(context, "Check Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //Likes Feature

        if (InternetStatus.getInstance(holder.blogLikeBtn.getContext()).isOnline()) {

        holder.blogLikeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                        if(!task.getResult().exists()){

                            Map<String, Object> likesMap = new HashMap<>();
                            likesMap.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

                            firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).set(likesMap);

                        } else {

                            firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).delete();

                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });
        }else{

            Toast.makeText(context, "Check Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        if (InternetStatus.getInstance(holder.blogCommentBtn.getContext()).isOnline()) {
            holder.blogCommentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent commentIntent = new Intent(context, CommentsActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(commentIntent);

                }
            });
        }else{

                Toast.makeText(context, "Check Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return blog_list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private View mView;

        private TextView descView;
        private ImageView blogImageView;
        private TextView blogDate;

        private TextView blogUserName;
        private CircleImageView blogUserImage;

        private ImageView blogLikeBtn;
        private TextView blogLikeCount;

        private ImageView blogCommentBtn;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

            blogLikeBtn = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_like_btn);
            blogCommentBtn = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_comment_icon);

        }

        public void setDescText(String descText){

            descView = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_desc);
            descView.setText(descText);

        }

        public void setBlogImage(String downloadUri, String thumbUri){

            blogImageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_image);

            RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
            requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder);

            if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing()) {
                Glide.with(context).applyDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions).load(downloadUri).thumbnail(
                        Glide.with(context).load(thumbUri)
                ).into(blogImageView);
            }
        }

        public void setTime(String date) {

            blogDate = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_date);
            blogDate.setText(date);

        }

        public void setUserData(String name, String image) {

            blogUserImage = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_user_image);
            blogUserName = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_user_name);

            blogUserName.setText(name);

            RequestOptions placeholderOption = new RequestOptions();
            placeholderOption.placeholder(R.drawable.profile_placeholder);

            if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing()) {
                Glide.with(context).applyDefaultRequestOptions(placeholderOption).load(image).into(blogUserImage);

            }
        }
        public void updateLikesCount(int count){

            blogLikeCount = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_like_count);
            blogLikeCount.setText(count + " Likes");

        }

    }

}
```

My MainActivity class is

```html
package com.nepalpolice.cdp;


import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {
    final Context context = this;
    private boolean exit = false;
    Dialog dialog;
    private Menu mymenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        Fragment fragment = new main();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();




        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

//Create Dialog


        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        mymenu = menu;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UpdateService.class);
                startService(intent);
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ImageView iv = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.iv_refresh, null);
                Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_refresh);
                rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                iv.startAnimation(rotation);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    item.setActionView(iv);
                }
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) {
                    new UpdateTask(this).execute();
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void resetUpdating()
    {
        // Get our refresh item from the menu
        MenuItem m = mymenu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            if(m.getActionView()!=null)
            {
                // Remove the animation.
                m.getActionView().clearAnimation();
                m.setActionView(null);
            }
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.store) {
            String url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Sagar%20Rawal&hl=en";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.contact) {
            Intent activity_about = new Intent(this, profile.class);
            startActivity(activity_about);

        }


        else if (id == R.id.tetris) {
            Intent activity_about = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(activity_about);

        }


        else if (id == R.id.tictac) {
            Intent activity_about = new Intent(this, MainMenuScreen.class);
            startActivity(activity_about);

        }


        else if (id == R.id.home) {
            main fragment = new main();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, "Main");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);


        }
         else if (id == R.id.email) {
            Intent activity_about = new Intent(this, Sendemail.class);
            startActivity(activity_about);
        } else if (id == R.id.call) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+9779868336847"));
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.share) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/pl" +
                    "ain");
            String shareBodyText = "Your shearing message goes here";
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject/Title");
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBodyText);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Via"));
        } else if (id == R.id.rate) {
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.nepalpolice.mnemonics&hl=en" + getPackageName())));
            }
            catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        (Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.faraksoch.sagar.eroutine&hl=en"))));
            }
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (exit)
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Really Exit?")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            // MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                            finish();
                            moveTaskToBack(true);
                        }
                    }).create().show();

        else {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.popBackStack();


            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() ==1) {
                finish();
            }

            exit = true;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    exit = false;
                }
            }, 800);

        }


    }


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not let this `Toast.show()` line called .

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. You write: "In B activity it shows "Check Internet", but when I press back button and move to A activty, Still toast message appears."  Do you mean the toast is shown again when you press the back button or do you mean the toast remains visible even once Activity A appears?

Comment: @Barns Toast appears to come and go in interval of 1-2 sec in A activity itself which is Mainactivity...It appears and then disappears....and after 15-20 sec..it disappears completely...Bizzare horror.

Comment: I haven't looked closely at the lifecycle of a `RecyclerView.Adapter` but you are calling toast three times in your `onBindViewHolder` method. checking each time if `isOnline`. Is there a reason that you check all these instances (eg. blogCommentBtn), won't they all be offline at the same time thus triggering toast multiple times? You can easily test this by slightly altering the toast message to "Check Internet 1", "Check Internet 2" ...

Comment: As I mentioned below in a comment. I believe you should not be checking "Online Status" in your `RecyclerAdapter` and most certainly not in your `onBindViewHolder` method as this will become quite expensive performance wise (checking isOnline each time a row is added)! I believe you should move the "Online Status"  check to the calling Activity or Fragment--unless you can provide a sound reason for your approach.

Comment: @Barns, I believe that too..I did checked online status in Recycleadapter because when device is offline and if i hit like button then...app crashes with error that client is offline....so when I implemented Online staus.....it removed that crashes..but if there is any bettter approach.I would like to learn how.

Comment: It certainly is possible for the connectivity to be dropped and there are listeners for detecting connectivity changes. But a more simple solution would be to add the `isOnline` check in your `onClick` or `onItemSelected` method and deal with the it there. BTW, you should be able to create a more robust app which does not `crash` because a method fails due to the lack of internet connectivity--try...catch can be a good friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that you have three places in your activity where you call this:

```
InternetStatus.getInstance(holder.blogLikeBtn.getContext()).isOnline()
```

If you do not have internet, you will call this line of code three times, and the three toasts will be created that appear sequentially; one after another:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Check Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

You should try and consolidate your code so that the toast is only shown one time. Consider the following code:

```
    if (InternetStatus.getInstance(holder.blogLikeBtn.getContext()).isOnline()) {
        //Get Likes
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).addSnapshotListener(((Main2Activity) context), new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "listening failed", e);
                    return;
                }

                if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_accent));
                    } else {
                        holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_accent));
                    }
                } else {

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_gray));
                    } else {
                        holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_gray));
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    holder.blogLikeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                    if(!task.getResult().exists()){

                        Map<String, Object> likesMap = new HashMap<>();
                        likesMap.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

                        firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).set(likesMap);

                    } else {

                        firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).delete();

                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });
        holder.blogCommentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent commentIntent = new Intent(context, CommentsActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(commentIntent);

            }
        });
    }else{

            Toast.makeText(context, "Check Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

Comment: Now I used your methode...now when I open B activity...Toast appears Once and when I pressed Back Button...It  appears again second time in Main activity...how should I cancel toast to appears when Back button is pressed?

Comment: and also I didn't use what you suggested, as it throwed me error on id of button which is after holder.button_id, So,  instead I removed two else statement and  didn't remove  if (InternetStatus.getInstance(holder.blogLikeBtn.getContext()).isOnline()) {    and kept only last  else statement......as you have mentioned above.

Comment: I have posted my A activity Code..Please check

Comment: Did you find the code?? can you suggest why second Toast appeared on back pressed from B activity to A and how to hide it??

Answer (score 0):

Create member `Toast mToast = null` and set it `mToast = Toast.makeText(context,...`. Then, in activity

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mToast != null) {
        mToast.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: where should I create member Toast mToast = null?? Is it on activity on adapter class and where should I place mToast=Toast.makeText....I'm sorry If I sounds stupid...but I'm starting on android watching tutorials from youtube and google...so It is hard for me to know where to place this element.

Comment: You should create and show Toasts in activity. Try to create method `public void showToast(String msg){mToast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);mToast.show();}` in activity and call it from Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

In `onBackPressed()` method of **Activity B** use this..

```
(new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    super.onBackPressed();
  }
}, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

`Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` is the **time interval** in `ms` for which the *toast shows* .

> The goal is to delay the the BackPressed for a span of time  ---- `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` as i have done above !!

Comment: Not a good solution. Intentionally delaying the app to "cure"  a symptom to a problem caused by the coder.

Comment: its not about *Just* toast, it could be some sort of **material animations** , the coder in those cases *must* delayy !! In most of the famous apps , you can see !! @Barns

Comment: But then again the coder does call toast three times in the same method in three different `if` conditionals where the condition of `isOffline` will certainly be the same.

Comment: I got your point , I just wrote a general solution , to eliminate his present problem  !! there might other complexities in *his* codee , too @Barns

Comment: Yes, I believe the OP has a few issues with his code. To be more specific to this problem, I see no reason to check online status in a `RecyclerAdapter`. In my opinion, it should be in the calling activity or fragment.